# ReactJS Updating Context in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am following differents tutorials I found online to use "Context" in ReactJS but I fail to make it work when I want to update the context in child pages. the code I use as a base comes from here : https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/
I use class components and here is what I have :

The component for context :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const UserContext = React.createContext()

class UserProvider extends Component {
  // Context state
  state = {
    user: {},
  }

  // Method to update state
  setUser = (user) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ user }))
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { user } = this.state
    const { setUser } = this

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{
          user,
          setUser,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default UserContext
export { UserProvider }
```

My App.js :

```
import FooterSPA from './components/FooterSPA/FooterSPA'

import UserContext, {UserProvider}  from './components/Context/UserContext'

// This component is the application entry point
class App extends Page {

  render() {

    const user = { lastname: 'langlois', firstname:"h", loggedIn: true }
    //const {user, setUser} = useState({ lastname: 'langlois', firstname:"hugo", loggedIn: true });

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
          {this.childComponents}
          {this.childPages}
          <FooterSPA homePath={this.props.locationPathname}/>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default withModel(App);
```

And Finally, the component where I try to do something FooterSPA :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import UserContext from '../Context/UserContext'

require('./FooterSPA.css');

export default class Footer extends Component {

  static contextType = UserContext

  render() {

    console.log(this.context);

    const { user, setUser } = this.context

    return (
        <div>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                const newUser = { name: 'Joe', loggedIn: true }
                setUser(newUser)
              }}
            >
              Update User
            </button>
            <div className="footerspa">
                <div className="footercontainer">
                    <Link to={this.props.homePath}>Back to Home Page</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I keep having an error saying that in FooterSP.js, "setUser" is not a function.
I tried to use "this.setUser" or "this.context.setUser" but it's the same.
I am very new to react and I guess I miss something obvious but I can't find what.
Also, I'm not sure how the Context.js component I created works so it's hard so troubleshoot for me.

I hope someone can help me, thank you in advance !
HL

I tried to change my App.js, or pass the function but I don't have knowledge with React so I don't even know what to do as a start

Comment: What version of React are you using? See if using `Footer.contextType = UserContext;` outside the component works instead of the `static contextType = UserContext` field. I'm curious, *why* are you trying to do this with React class components? Class components have been effectively deprecated since React hooks were release back in 2019. This would likely be like 10x easier using React function components. If you are interested in that I could help with that.

Comment: @Drew Reese, Even if I am new to react, after some browsing time I have seen indeed that class seems old. Even the new react site mentions only functions. but the company i work for created a framework around React and it uses classes so I have to get on with it. Thanks for your reply below it solved the issue

Comment: React class components are certainly still valid React, and may exist in older code bases. I haven't personally written a React Class component in years, and tend to convert our old class components to function components when enough of a feature change is requested from business. As long as you have good unit test coverage in place I'd say don't be afraid to convert old code to current React best practices when/where you can. Don't update just for the sake of updating, but if you are already there in the code to make changes you might as well improve it at the same time. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The `App` is rendering a *different* `UserContext.Provider` component and passing `user` as the context value, e.g. `this.context = { lastname: 'langlois', firstname:"h", loggedIn: true }` in the consuming components. There is no `setUser` function in this provided context value.

```
class App extends Page {
  render() {
    const user = { lastname: 'langlois', firstname:"h", loggedIn: true }
    //const {user, setUser} = useState({ lastname: 'langlois', firstname:"hugo", loggedIn: true });

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}> // <-- no "setUser" property
        {this.childComponents}
        {this.childPages}
        <FooterSPA homePath={this.props.locationPathname} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

### Solutions

Either create state in `App` and pass what the consumers expect:

```
class App extends Page {
  state = {
    lastname: 'langlois',
    firstname: "hugo",
    loggedIn: true
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{ user: this.state, setUser: this.setState }}
      >
        {this.childComponents}
        {this.childPages}
        <FooterSPA homePath={this.props.locationPathname} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Or import and render the `UserProvider` from the first snippet.

```
import FooterSPA from './components/FooterSPA/FooterSPA'
import { UserProvider }  from './components/Context/UserContext';

class App extends Page {
  render() {
    return (
      <UserProvider> // <-- provides { user, setUser }
        {this.childComponents}
        {this.childPages}
        <FooterSPA homePath={this.props.locationPathname} />
      </UserProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withModel(App);
```